# UHF RFID and Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I would like to write an application that can read and write to RFID tags. The application will be build with Cordova and the device will have an integrated UHF RFID scanner, like this device http://sdgsystems.com/download/Marketing/Datasheets/ATID/AT511%2020140305%5B1%5D.pdf. Are there currently plugins that are able to communicate with the RFID scanner? Searched the net but didn't find any. I can write the plugin myself but I need a starting point, how do I communicate with it?

Comment: Can somebody direct me in the right direction? Is it wise to use cordova if you are communicating with these type of devices?

Comment: Not an answer as the SO cops will whine... I've used this plugin several times with good success in cordova apps... https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc

Answer (score 2):

If you have a generic iOS or Android device, there's a UHF RFID reader from a company called [U Grok It](https://www.ugrokit.com) that plugs into the audio port, and has a Cordova and Xamarin SDK (as well as native iOS and Android SDKs).

This isn't an embedded device, but provides flexibility if you're looking for a more general solution using Cordova.